# JavaScript Object.assign not working on Date object

Tags: javascript, date, object, clone, assign

Regular objects can be cloned using this method:

```
a = {x:9}; //sample
b = Object.assign(Object.create(a),a);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

However, the variables of Date type don't seem to work with Object.assign and Object.create:

```
a = new Date();
b = Object.assign(Object.create(a),a);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

/*
Results of printing a, b are not the same:
a:
Thu Oct 20 2016 11:17:29 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
b:
Date {}
*/
```

I know I can create a clone of Date object another way using

```
b = new Date(a)
```

But why are Object.assign and Object.create not working on Date type?

Comment: What is it that you're expecting to happen? What properties of the source Date object do you expect to be copied?

Comment: all of its properties

Comment: Well it **is** copying over all of the *enumerable* and *own* properties. It's just that a  Date instance doesn't have any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Object.assign()` method copies over the *enumerable* and *own* properties of the source object. A Date instance doesn't really have any of those (if you don't add any with your own code).

In particular, Date "properties" like the year, month, date, etc. aren't properties in the JavaScript sense. They're values that can be retrieved via the API. That doesn't make them properties.

Comment: hm, JS is funny, it seems an instance of Date type is having "native" properties not accessible by JS code

Comment: @johnlowvale yes, that's entirely within the purview of native elements, though pure JavaScript code can have ways of doing that too. Object properties are right there as properties on the object, and as you can see from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) there really aren't any on a Date instance.

Comment: Better to reference [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-date-instances). Default Date instances have one internal property (their time value, accessible through *getTime*) and no own properties.